# Saber cuánto tiempo ha pasado con PHP

Tags: php

hola quiero hacer una condición que me borre unos registros de mi base de datos si ha pasado 'n' meses en la base de datos tengo una columna 'fecha_creacion' que es un timestamp y estoy recogiendo los meses en forma de enteros en la variable $meses hice un var_dump asi

```
   var_dump($intervalo->format('se deben borrar si ya paso %m meses'),$mesesPas->format('y han pasado %m meses'),($mesesPas > $intervalo));
        die();
```

Ese me esta arrojando :

string(34) "se deben borrar si ya paso 1 meses"

string(20) "y han pasado 4 meses"

bool(false)

El problema es que siempre me da false y nunca se ejecuta mi código en la condición

```
$meses = ($_GET['meses']);
    $hoy = new DateTime("now");
    $creacion = new DateTime($row['fecha_creacion']);
    $mesesPas = date_diff($creacion,$hoy); 
    $intervalo = new DateInterval('P'.$meses.'M');

    if($mesesPas > $intervalo){
    do something

    }
```

¿Alguna idea de porque no funciona?¿estoy indicando mal no condición? ¿o los datainterval no son el mismo formato que los DataTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo he probado y me imprime siempre true, dado que intervalo al no tener año siempre sera menor, puedes intentar con

```
if($mesesPas->m > $intervalo->m) {
}
```

Comment: Excelente es lo que necesitaba y tienes razon ahora ya funciona correctamente gracias (y).